# Why does my insert not add product information into MySql database in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, insert

I am trying to insert a product into MySQL using a PHP form and I have debugged the code and the variables show that the information is there, but when it is done debugging and I look at the product list, not is inserted.

This is the code for the action to add a product in the index.php file:

```
} else if($action == 'add_product') {
    $product_code = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'productCode');
    $name = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'name');
    $version = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'version');
    $release_date = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'releaseDate');
    if ($product_code == NULL || $name == NULL || $version == NULL || 
            $release_date == NULL) {
        $error = "Invalid product data. Check all fields and try again.";
        include('../errors/error.php');             
    } else {
        add_product($product_code, $name, $version, $release_date);
        $products = get_products();
        include 'product_list.php';
    }

}
```

This is the code for the add_product function:

```
function add_product($product_code, $name, $version, $release_date) {
    global $db;
    $query = 'INSERT INTO products
                 (productCode, name, version, releaseDate)
              VALUES
                 (:product_code, :name, :version, :release_date)';
    $statement = $db->prepare($query);
    $statement->bindValue(':product_code', $product_code);
    $statement->bindValue(':name', $name);
    $statement->bindValue(':version', $version);
    $statement->bindValue(':release_date', $release_date);
    $statement->execute();
    $statement->closeCursor();
}
```

And this is the code for the product_add.php file:

```
<div id= "main">
    <h1>
        Add Product
    </h1>
    <form action="index.php" method="post"
              id="add_product_form">
        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="add_product">

         <table id="no_border">
             <tr>
                 <td><label>Code:</label></td>
                 <td><input type="text" name="productCode"required></td><br>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label>Name:</label></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="name"required></td><br>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label>Version:</label></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="version"required></td><br>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label>Release Date:</label></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="releaseDate"required></td>
            <td><p>Use 'yyyy-mm-dd' format</p></td>
            </tr>
            <label>&nbsp;</label>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="submit" value="Add Product"></td>           
            </tr>
        </form>
    </table>
    <p class="last_paragraph">
        <a href="index.php?action=list_products" >View Product List</a>
    </p>
</div>
```

Can anyone give me any direction as to what I might be missing or doing wrong?  Thank you in advance for any help with this.

Comment: Are these definitely the right column names in your table? `productCode, name, version, releaseDate`

Comment: What error are you getting exactly?

Comment: "how that the information is there"  The information is _where_ exactly? Have you confirmed that your `add_product()` function is being called?  Have you dumped the variable values _within_ that function?

Comment: If you're just getting started with PHP and want to build applications, I'd strongly recommend looking at various [development frameworks](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/best-php-frameworks/) to see if you can find one that fits your style and needs. They come in various flavors from lightweight like [Fat-Free Framework](https://fatfreeframework.com/) to far more comprehensive like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/). These give you concrete examples to work from and guidance on how to write your code and organize your project's files.

Comment: @MarkOverton That is correct.

Comment: @theminer3746  There is not error.  The function completes, but it does not add the entry into the database.

Comment: @PatrickQ  When I debug the issue, the variables all show the information that I added.  It's just not being inserted into the database.

Comment: @tadman  Got it.  Thank you tadman.

Comment: @MarinoB  Please describe in detail exactly what the debugging was that you did.  _Where_ and _how_ were you checking the values of the variables?